# Cancel Button Functionality in C# and XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, cancel-button

I am trying to hash out the functionality of a cancel button for a WPF App.  Currently there are 2 functions I am focusing on:

```
    private void AnalysisClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        model.RunAnalysis();
    }
    private void CancelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        model.RunAnalysis().Abort;  //Pseudo-code, needs help!
        MessageBox.Show("The Analysis was cancelled.", "Operation Cancelled", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    }
```

The ' AnalysisClick ' function is started with a button called Begin.  The goal of the ' CancelClick ' button is to stop the Analysis and to provide a dialog box informing the user that the test was stopped.  What is the best way to achieve this?

**EDIT**
I am currently looking into `BackgroundWorker` and [Microsoft Asynchronous Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) per Users' suggestions.

Comment: I would probably use a `BackgroundWorker` with `WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;`

Comment: Either a `BackgroundWorker` or a `Task` and a `CancellationToken` (needs .Net 4.0 or better)

Comment: Note that cancellation support in your `BackgroundWorker` task is something you have to build into your analysis -- checking as you go whether the user has requested to cancel. Also, "canceled" has only one "l" in American English.

Comment: Check [microsoft Asynchronous Programming model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This will help you resolve your query.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies!  The only thing of note is that it is unfortunately required to be in .Net 3.5.  But I will look into the `BackgroundWorker` for sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments above to your question, but if you want to try something quickly Tasks are a great way to do async operation with ability to cancel those tasks. Something like this should work or at least get you started:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cancelAnalysisTask = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Task _analysisTask;

    private void AnalysisClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _analysisTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                if (_cancelAnalysisTask.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                model.RunAnalysis();
            });
    }

    private void CancelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_analysisTask != null)
        {
            _cancelAnalysisTask.Cancel();
            _analysisTask = null;
            MessageBox.Show("The Analysis was cancelled.", "Operation Cancelled", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }
```

This is a quick write-up, what I would recommend is putting async functionality into your ViewModel and expose Commands. UI shouldn't really know the details of operations. Then Cancelling the Task can be written near/before the meat of the operation within the ViewModel, where it makes more sense to abort the expensive operation/loop/etc.